# Tell saslauthd to reject authentication attempts for all domains other than ours

Tags: postfix, kerberos, saslauthd

We are running Postfix and require authentication for the sending of mail through SMTP. The authentication uses Cyrus' `saslauthd` which does a Kerberos authentication against our Kerberos domain.

Is there a way to tell `saslauthd` to attempt authentications only to the Kerberos domain `MYDOMAIN.ORG` and to simply reject any other domains? That is, to not even try to authenticate for other domains?

Or, if `saslauthd` does not allow that, can Postfix be configured to reject authentication attempts from users with domains other than ours?

We are running all of this on Debian `buster` (sasl version 2.1.27, postfix 3.4.14).